# how to select only first td of first colgroup of table?

Tags: css

how to select only first `td` of first `colgroup` of `table`? if i have `table` with 5 column and using 5 `colgroup`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

<del>table colgroup:first-child td:first-child</del>

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp):

> **Note:** For `:first-child` to work in IE a `<!DOCTYPE>`  must be declared.

**Update:**

As DisgruntledGoat mentions correctly, `td` elements are not descendants of `colgroup` elements. But the first `colgroup` obviously always includes the first column so this

```
table tr td:first-child
```

which selects the first `td` in every row, should do it.

Comment: Did this actually work? Table cells are not actually descendants of colgroup tags, they are only descendants of rows.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Now that you mention it, you are right, this should not work. Sorry for the false information, I was more concentrating on `:first-child`. But anyway the first `colgroup` always includes the first column, so it is something similar.